# why does my background move when i scroll?

Tags: css

Every time I scroll the background-text keeps following wherever I scroll to. How can I get it to stay right where I want it to be at.

```
 .bg-image {
      background-image: url(../construction/3.jpg);
      filter: blur(8px);
      -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
      height: 100%;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }

.bg-text {
  background-color: #000; 
  background-color: #000; 
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: please you can show with picture? i don't understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you fixed image,you can use :
`.your-class{
    background-image: url("your-image");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;`
}`

Answer (score 0):

you should have the background image fixed, so

```html
 .bg-image {
      background-image: url(../construction/3.jpg);
      filter: blur(8px);
      -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
      height: 100%;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-attachment: fixed;
    }
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-attachment
I hope this link would help.

Comment: I actually want the opposite of that. I don't want the image to scroll down with me. I want it to stay in place in where I left my .bg-image.